# TFS Get SQL changes from last build

Tags: c#, tfs, workflow-activity

I am currently working on a build definition for a TFS Implementation. I have almost everything working except i cannot get this last part to work.
Below is the CodeActivity class that I am currently implementing.

In the workflow diagram i am utilising the default `associatedChangesets` variable as the InArgument.

The following code works and creates the folder `Database` but the `AssociatedChangesets` does not seem to contain any items.

```
public sealed class CreateDatabaseDrop : CodeActivity
    {

        public InArgument<Workspace> Workspace { get; set; }
        public InArgument<string> DropLocation { get; set; }
        public InArgument<IList<Changeset>> AssociatedChangesets { get; set; }
        // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
        // and return the value from the Execute method.

        Workspace workspace;
        string dropLocation;
        IList<Changeset> associatedChangesets;
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            List<string> filesChanged = new List<string>();
            workspace = context.GetValue(this.Workspace);
            dropLocation = context.GetValue(this.DropLocation);
            associatedChangesets = context.GetValue(this.AssociatedChangesets);

            if (!Directory.Exists(dropLocation + @"\database\"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dropLocation + @"\database\");

            foreach (var c in associatedChangesets.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate))
            {
                foreach (var change in c.Changes)
                {
                    context.WriteBuildMessage(change.Item.ServerItem);
                }
                foreach (var change in c.Changes.Where(x => x.Item.ItemType == ItemType.File && x.Item.ServerItem.Split('/').Last().ToLower().Contains(".sql")))
                {
                    string fileName = change.Item.ServerItem.Split('/').Last();
                    context.WriteBuildMessage(string.Format("SQL File Found: {0}", change.Item.ServerItem));
                    WorkingFolder wf = workspace.GetWorkingFolderForServerItem(change.Item.ServerItem);
                    string copyFrom = Path.Combine(wf.LocalItem, fileName),
                    copyTo = dropLocation + @"\database\" + fileName;
                    context.WriteBuildMessage(string.Format("Copying {0} to {1}", fileName, copyTo));
                    File.Copy(copyFrom, copyTo, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Would anyone be able to help me figure out how to get All SQL changes since the last build was done.

Comment: Where about in the Workflow are you dropping your activity? Are you getting the value from an `IBuildDetail.AssociatedChangesets` or a variable called `associatedChangesets` in the scope of a sequence?

Comment: I am using the variable associatedChangesets that is on the Default Xaml template.

Comment: @DaveShaw is there anyway in code to get the associated changesets. i have been trying to do some searches but i dont really know how to query the workspace to do this.

Comment: OR, if you have "Associate Changesets and Work Items" set to true in your build definition, then you can use `associatedChangesets` after the `AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems` happens.

Comment: I thought i did, its part of the company policy. i didnt think of verifying that this was set. thanks for some ideas i will let you know if this works out.

Comment: @DaveShaw I have checked the XAML and the build configuration for the `AssociatedChangesetsAndWorkItems` and this property is set to true. But it is not getting the changesets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found how to do this. I will put most of the code below for future reference and people who run into the same problems.

```
    public sealed class CreateDatabaseDrop : CodeActivity
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<Workspace> Workspace { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<IBuildDefinition> BuildDefinition { get; set; }
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> ProjectName { get; set; }
        Workspace workspace;

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            workspace = context.GetValue(this.Workspace);
            IBuildDefinition buildDef = context.GetValue(this.BuildDefinition);
            DateTime? comparison = null;
            var details = buildDef.QueryBuilds().Where(x => x.Status == BuildStatus.Succeeded).OrderBy(x => x.StartTime);
            if (details.Count() > 0)
            {
                comparison = details.Last().StartTime;
            }
            if (!comparison.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }
            IEnumerable history = workspace.VersionControlServer.QueryHistory("$/" + context.GetValue(ProjectName),
                VersionSpec.Latest,
                0,
                RecursionType.Full,
                null,
                new DateVersionSpec(comparison.Value),
                VersionSpec.Latest,
                Int32.MaxValue,
                true,
                false);

            foreach (Changeset c in history.OfType<Changeset>().OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate))
            {
                foreach (var change in c.Changes.Where(x => x.Item.ItemType == ItemType.File
                    && x.Item.ServerItem.Split('/').Last().ToLower().Contains(".sql")
                    && (x.ChangeType != (ChangeType.Delete | ChangeType.SourceRename | ChangeType.Rename))))
                {
                    string fileName = change.Item.ServerItem.Split('/').Last();
                    WorkingFolder wf = workspace.TryGetWorkingFolderForServerItem(change.Item.ServerItem);
                    if (wf != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wf.LocalItem))
                    {
                        context.WriteBuildMessage(string.Format("SQL File found: {0}", fileName));

                    }
                }
            }
    }
```